# Laravel passing @json into dataset results in wrong data

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to pass a Collection to my Javascript using the data-* attribute as follows

```
<div id="map" data-tiles="@json($tiles)"></div>
```

When I console.log this using `console.log(el.dataset.tiles)`  I receive only `[{` in javascript.

#### I've tried

- Parse and stringify result in JS using `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(el.dataset.tiles)));` but it returns the same `[{` result.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem recently.

Using double quotes will break the json because the browser takes everything between first opening and closing double quotes to be the value of the attribute (in your case`[{`).

On the other hand, if you use it with single quotes, it works just fine:

```
<div ... data-tiles='@json($tiles)'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this

```
 var tiles = @json($tiles)
```

Then perform console.log(el.dataset.tiles).

Comment: I got it working like that as well, but I want to pass the variables using data attributes

Comment: @MiguelStevens I am not sure can you send entire collection to JavaScript without doing @json?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
<div id="map" data-tiles="{{ $tiles->toJson() }}"></div>
```

That is how I do

Comment: That does work when I parse it with `JSON.parse(mapEl.dataset)`, so if you add that to your answer I can accept it.